# How to click on the age verification popup window in Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, webdriver

I am trying to use Selenium to search something in Aliexpress, but when I search for some products, for example, when I type "test," I will have a popup window that requests my age verification, as shown below:
[image: The popup window]

I am trying to click on "I AM OVER 18" by driver, but nothing works

The code I used is:

```
def aliexpress_driver():
    url = 'https://www.aliexpress.com/'
    global browser
    browser = webdriver.Chrome()
    browser.get(url)


def search_for(product):
    aliexpress_driver()
search = browser.find_element("id","search-key").send_keys("test")
    SearchBtn_xpath = r'//*[@id="form-searchbar"]/div[1]/input'
    search_btn = browser.find_element(By.XPATH,SearchBtn_xpath)

    browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", search_btn)
    time.sleep(10)

    p = r'/html/body/div[8]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]'
    browser.find_element(By.XPATH,p ).click
    print("Clicked")
```

I always got the error:
`selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[8]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]"}`

Note:
I tried the following things:

1- `WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, p))).click()`

2- I also tried to use CSS selector, using class name

The HTML element is :
`<div class="law18--btn--29ue4Ne law18--left--2XI39FE" data-spm-anchor-id="a2g0o.productlist.0.i23.4ac93c4fzXPnR5">I AM OVER 18    </div>`

can you help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply click on `I AM OVER 18` tab by:

1. wait for the web element to get visibly located.
2. then find the element using `CSS_SELECTOR` and click.

Here's how you may try:

```py
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome, Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
import selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions as EC

def aliexpress_driver():
    url = 'https://www.aliexpress.com/'
    browser = Chrome()
    browser.get(url)
    return browser

def search_for(product):
    browser = aliexpress_driver()
    wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)

    search = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'search-key')))
    search.send_keys(product)
    search.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

    # wait for the element to get located to click
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.law18--btn--29ue4Ne.law18--left--2XI39FE'))).click()
    print("Clicked")
    sleep(5)

search_for('test')
```

output:

```
Clicked
```